# Java Error: "code too large public void draw( )"

Tags: java, genexus

When I attempt to run Developer Menu, I get the following error and warnings:

```
GeneXus Java Make v1.0
com\alpharoovs\inspectionform_impl.java:220: error: code too large
   public void draw( )
               ^
Note: com\alpharoovs\inspectionform_impl.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: com\alpharoovs\inspectionform_impl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

failed ( error code=1)
Build failed.
DeveloperMenu Compilation for Default (Java Web) Failed
Run Developer Menu Failed
```

At this point, I'm only interested in resolving the "code too large" error.

Comment: In order to help you better, you should let us know which version of GeneXus you're using. What kind of object inspectionform is?

Answer (score 0):

I've split it into smaller pieces, and that has resolved the issue.